# CSS positioning images and text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get some text between two images.  The images are positioned correctly, but there are some weird design issues that are cropping up.

[Current Page](http://www.phnx.org/dia/index.html) (web page)

[Design Plan](http://www.phnx.org/dia/example.jpg) (jpg)

What I'm trying to figure out is this:

1. Background must stop before the right edge of the right image (the girl)

   Background must extend the height of the right image

   Vertical bar underneath left edge of right image.

   Text wrapping before vertical bar

   Bars to left of bottom text in center

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You have a small error in your HTML which may influence the CSS.

<div class=top-text"> is missing a ".

Comment: Good catch.  Didn't affect anything, but I like to have it be clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd advise against splitting the image up, as Aiden suggests. This is messy and not exactly a modern way to go about it. Try something like this:

```
.top-pic {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -200px;
}
```

Change the margin-top assignment to however high you want the image in pixels. The only issue left is to scale the width of the top-text div to accommodate the image. One way to do this would be to set `padding-right: 250px;` or so to `.top-text h1` and `.top-text h2`.

Comment: Margins are solving all my issues.  Hopefully they're browser-independent.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit wrong

```
    .top-pic {
    position: absolute;
    top: -5.7em;
    right: -1.5em;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Cut this image into 2 images (one in the header next to the tabs, and one in the content). Stuff is floating underneath because of your z-index.

In your CSS. What you want is a pretty basic fixed 3-col layout with the text in the middle. I will point you here:

http://layouts.ironmyers.com/

http://www.csszengarden.com/

That is how CSS layouts are done.

Comment: Hrm.  I'd prefer not to chop the image in half, especially if they want to change it.  I'll look at your links.

Comment: I can understand that. Just a quick suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you move the top-pic above your logo and change the styling you can get a similar effect to what you want.

```
<div class="top-pic">
  <img src="index2_files/girlbird.png">
</div>
<div class="logo">
  <img src="index2_files/logo-center.png">
</div>
```

CSS Changes

```
.top-pic {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
    right: -25px;
}
```